# Universal Tween Engine Serial sequence

Tags: java, libgdx, tween

I need to create a sequence where we have the following;

object 1 moves from point A to point B in 2 seconds
at the same time, object 2 moves from point c to D in one second, and serial to that, object 3 moves from F to G in one second.

As you can see.  This needs the following chain

```
Timeline.createSequence()
.beginParallel()
    .push( Tween.set( 1 , XY ).target( B )
    .begingSerial() 
        .push( Tween.to( 2, XY).target( D )
        .push( Tween.to( 3, XY).target( G )
    .end()
.end()
```

But "beginSerial()" does not exists.  How do I do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always push another `TimeLine` into the original `TimeLine`.

```
Timeline.createSequence()
.beginParallel()
    .push( Tween.set( 1 , XY ).target( B )
    .push( Timeline.createSequence()
        .push( Tween.to( 2, XY).target( D )
        .push( Tween.to( 3, XY).target( G )
    .end() )
.end()
```

Hope this helps.
Good Luck.